# Best way to retrieve certain part of link url?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, extract

I'm looping through some li's which contains of links.

The links can look like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/mlp/books/">Books</a>
```

... as well as ...

```
<a href="movies/">Movies</a>
```

What I want is to retrieve the last level of the link (books and movies in the cases above) and put them into an array.

What is the best way to do that?

```
var listOptions = [];

$('#navigation ul').each(function(index){
    var link = $(this).children().html();
    ?
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your HTML structure is exactly, but assuming you can get to the anchor tags:

```
$('a').each(function (index) {
    var tokens = this.href.split('/')
        , link = tokens[tokens.length - 2];

    // link is now "books" or "movies"
});
```

Note that this also assumes that all of the links have a trailing `/`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JVQsm/

Answer (score 1):

I would use [jQuery `map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) like so;

```
var listOptions = $('#navigation ul').map(function () {
    var href = $(this).find('a').prop('href');

    // Handle a trailing '/', which will screw things up
    if (href.slice(-1) === '/') {
        href = href.slice(0, -1);
    }

    var last = href.lastIndexOf('/');

    // Handle href="foo";
    if (last === -1) {
        last = 0;
    }

    // Return the last part of the URL.
    return href.slice(last);
}).get();
```

`listOptions` will now be an array of the last parts of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

To put them in an array :

```
var listOptions = $.map($('#navigation ul li a'), function(el,i) { 
    return el.href.slice(0,-1).split('/').pop();
});

//listOptions now contains ['books', 'movies'] etc
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uf4rb/)

To just replace them on the site:

```
$('#navigation ul li a').attr('href', function(i, href) {
    var arr = href.split('/');
    return arr[arr.length-2]+'/';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uf4rb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var listOptions = [];

$('a').each(function () {
    var trimmed = $(this).prop('href').slice(0, -1);
    listOptions.push(trimmed.substring(trimmed.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
});
```

You have trailing `/` in all links. If that is always the case, you need to remove it first.
That is stored in `trimmed` variable, and then the last part is extracted.

If that is not always the case, you could expand the logic a little. Check if the last char is `/`, than remove it. If it is not, you don't remove anything